# Re-signed AppStore .ipa to Enterprise In-House crashing

Tags: ios, code-signing, ipa, codesign

In my project we created an `.ipa` using our AppStore certificates from our Apple Developer Account. Moreover our customer want us to re-sign the  `.ipa` using their Enterprise In-house certificate and provisioning profile from their Apple Enterprise Account in order to them to be able to distribute the app internally.
However, after installing the `.ipa` in a device without any error shown, the app starts but immediately crashes. I was able to get the following logs:

> Bootstrapping failed for  with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID com.com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x282068ff0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx[0x333f][62], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx[0x333f][62], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:com.com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx[0x333f][62], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}

I have already double-checked the expiration dates of the certificate and provisioning profile, also in trust they are set to `Use System Defaults`, and both look match each other as well. Also, i'm updating the bundle identifier in `Info.plist` file and updating the `Entitlements.plist` as well.
For code-signing I have already used tools like `iResign` or `EasyResign`, and a manual procedure described [here](https://medium.com/@krunaldarji810/re-sign-your-ios-application-ad04a833623).

Any idea of what may be the problem?

**UPDATE**: I was able to fix the problem by building the initial .ipa with Development certificate instead of AppStore certificate (as @below suggested), before re-signing it with customer's Enterprise In-House certificate. The problem looks to be that Apple somewhat encripts the binary of AppStore signed apps making that when we re-sign not all the app is fully re-signed. As such, from what I could learn, when re-signing is required and when customer doesn't deliver us an Apple Account but only the bundle identifier, certificate and provisioning profile, I would suggest on our side to codesign the .ipa with either Development or Ad-Hoc (not tested but probably works as well) certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Enterprise certificate … why are you not building the app with it in the first place?

If you do not have it: My experience is that it is preferable to build the app with a developer certificate that matches the desired bundle identifier, and then re-sign.

Comment: Regarding your first point, yes I have the Enterprise certificate, but to build the app with it shouldn't I have credentials to the Enterprise Account? Because this is something I have not. From what I know (I may be wrong), in order to build an app I am required to have the credentials of the Apple Account associated to the certificates. But I only have Apple Account credentials for an Apple Development Account and not for the Apple Enterprise one which belongs to my customer.

Comment: No, if you have the provisioning profile and the certificate, you can sign the app using Xcode. Of course, not using automatic signing

Comment: When I go Archive -> Distribute App -> Enterprise -> Manually manage signing, only distribution certificates that belongs to the team of our Apple Development Account appears. I am not able to select a different team. Am I missing something? Thanks for you replies

Comment: Did you import the certificate into your keychain?

Comment: I have imported it and is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I was able to fix the problem by building the initial `.ipa` with Development certificate instead of AppStore certificate (as @below suggested), before re-signing it with customer's Enterprise In-House certificate. The problem looks to be that Apple somewhat encripts the binary of AppStore signed apps making that when we re-sign not all the app is fully re-signed. As such, from what I could learn, when re-signing is required and when customer doesn't deliver us an Apple Account but only the bundle identifier, certificate and provisioning profile, I would suggest on our side to codesign the `.ipa` with either Development or Ad-Hoc (not tested but probably works as well) certificates.